# Laravel Vite TailwindCSS classes don't apply

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

TailwindCSS classes dont work in Vite project

I created new laravel project:

`laravel new example-app`

Then I created 'vite' for use vue:
`npm create vite@latest  (then selected Vue, project name is 'backend', selected  JS)`

Then did it:

```
cd backend
npm install
npm run dev
```

Then I tried to  install Tailwind.css  (on **backend** folder)

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

In **tailwind.config.js** added this:

```
content: [
        "./index.html",
        "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
```

in src folder  created  file index.css and added this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

In src/main.js  added this:

```
'import './index.css';
```

Then in **App.vue** tried add html:

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
        Hello world!
</h1>
```

But system doesn't see classes `'text-3xl font-bold underline'`

I tried several times but it doesnt work.

If add tailwind to main project (using webpack mix) it works , but if I created Vite project inside and want to add there it doesn't work.

How can I fix it?